# How do you use a string across classes?

Tags: java, class

## How do you use the string defined by the user in an if/else-if statement in different classes.

An Example code(with error):

```
public class blah_blah
{
    public void example1()
        {
        if(input_str.toLowerCase().startsWith("b"))
            {
                pronoun = "he";
                gender = "boy";
            }
        else if(input_str.toLowerCase().startsWith("g"))
            {
                pronoun = "she";
                gender = "girl";
            }
        }
}
public class blah
{
    public void example2()
    {
        System.out.println("it's a " + example1.gender + ", " + example1.pronoun + " beautiful");
    }
}
```

Comment: with error? What error?

Comment: of u cant use local variable in other block first read what is local variables and class variables.

Comment: what? i cant read the beginning.

Comment: @Lioninn22 i would ask you to read types of variables and how it is used. and one thing is that is basic and if u read rather then just use prepare example. that will be more good to you i have maintain link in my answer see that :)

Comment: @Krishna so I want to use it across classes so i use static. but then i want to change it in my class and it doesn't change what do i do?

Comment: @Lioninn22 means after using it u want to set its value from other class??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a getter. The Java naming convention would be

```
class Example1 {
    private String gender;
    private String pronoun;

    public void example1(String input_str) {
        if (input_str.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")) {
            pronoun = "he";
            gender = "boy"; // male?
        } else if (input_str.toLowerCase().startsWith("g")) {
            pronoun = "she";
            gender = "girl"; // female?
        }
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public String getPronoun() {
        return pronoun;
    }
}
```

Then you need to call `example1`, something like

```
Example1 exe = new Example1();
exe.example1("boy");
System.out.println(exe.getGender());
```

Comment: I would Strongly recommend to give him link for learning for the basic.

Comment: @Lioninn22 Did you call `example1` first. Read my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you first read about the variables. here. [Types of variables.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm)

here what u want to do that example is also there.

```
public class Student {

   public String name;  // Student's name.
   public double test1, test2, test3;   // Grades on three tests.

   public double getAverage() {  // compute average test grade
      return (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only static variables can be accecssed in different classes. Local variable is not possible to access from outside class. You can use getter setter to set and get the variables.